# How do I get the assigned numeric value of string in loop?

Tags: r

In the following code below I want to get the number for `pattern[i]` instead of pattern itself in `get_number`. Thanks

```
pattern <- c("Ago2_1","Ago2_2", "WT_1", "WT_2", "DCLd_1", "DCLd_2")

  ##STATS  
  Ago2_1    <-  299117512
  Ago2_2    <-  29564885
  DCLd_1    <-  67004254
  DCLd_2    <-  77682528
  WT_1      <-  27073135
  WT_2      <-  113214012

for ( i in 1:length(pattern)){
get_number <- pattern [i]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()`. In your `for` loop, `i` is one of the strings in `pattern`. Therefore, just use `get()` to retrieve its numeric value and store it somewhere (in this example, in a list).

```
pattern <- c("Ago2_1","Ago2_2", "WT_1", "WT_2", "DCLd_1", "DCLd_2")

##STATS  
Ago2_1    <-  29911751
Ago2_2    <-  29564885
DCLd_1    <-  67004254
DCLd_2    <-  77682528
WT_1      <-  27073135
WT_2      <-  113214012

# initialize a collector
get_number <- list()
for ( i in pattern){
  get_number[[(length(get_number) + 1)]] <- get(i)
}

get_number

[[1]]
[1] 29911751

[[2]]
[1] 29564885

[[3]]
[1] 27073135

[[4]]
[1] 113214012

[[5]]
[1] 67004254
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mget` to return the values in a `list`

```
mget(pattern)
#$Ago2_1
#[1] 29911751

#$Ago2_2
#[1] 29564885

#$WT_1
#[1] 27073135

#$WT_2
#[1] 113214012

#$DCLd_1
#[1] 67004254

#$DCLd_2
#[1] 77682528
```